# Cannot set IndexMemory and DataMemory on MySQL Cluster

Tags: mysql

I am in the process of setting up a MySQL Cluster (version 7.2.4) on 64-bit Debian Linux.  The cluster has two management/SQL nodes and two data nodes.  Each server has the following in **/var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini**:

```
[NDBD DEFAULT]
NoOfReplicas=2
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
DataMemory=256M
IndexMemory=64M

[MYSQLD DEFAULT]

[NDB_MGMD DEFAULT]

[TCP DEFAULT]

# Management node 1
[NDB_MGMD]
NodeId=1
HostName=192.168.25.10
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

# Management node 2
[NDB_MGMD]
NodeId=2
HostName=192.168.25.11
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

# Storage node 1
[NDBD]
NodeId=3
HostName=192.168.25.12

# Storage node 2
[NDBD]
NodeId=4
HostName=192.168.25.13

[MYSQLD]
NodeId=5
HostName=192.168.25.10

[MYSQLD]
NodeId=6
HostName=192.168.25.11

[MYSQLD]
[MYSQLD]
```

The documentation and my own research on Google leads me to believe that this will set the data memory to 256 MB and the index memory to 64 MB.  However, when the cluster is started using this configuration, these settings are not honored:

```
mysql> SELECT node_id, memory_type, total FROM ndbinfo.memoryusage;
+---------+--------------+----------+
| node_id | memory_type  | total    |
+---------+--------------+----------+
|       3 | Data memory  | 83886080 |
|       3 | Index memory | 19136512 |
|       4 | Data memory  | 83886080 |
|       4 | Index memory | 19136512 |
+---------+--------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

For each node, the data memory is 80 MB and the index memory is 18 MB, which are the default values according to the MySQL Cluster documentation.

I've tried a few minor tweaks, such as changing the [NDBD DEFAULT] to [ndbd default], but nothing has worked.  Does anyone know why I'm not able to change these two settings?

As always, any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Good question. Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem even after restarting the manager with -reload and -initial.

Comment: I believe I did solve this, but I honestly don't remember how.  Shortly after I posted this, we had a serious server failure and spent a few days recovering from it, so I never documented the MySQL Cluster like I wanted to.  Try the suggested fix in Bernd's comment below.  If it works, I'll mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. I got this working now after realizing that these were Data-Node rather than SQL-Node metrics. For my case I removed one of the Data Nodes and increased the Memory of the remainder, then restarted NDBD with the --initial flag, which is needed when these parameters change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when starting both management servers with the new configuration: did you restart the management nodes with --reload to actually load the new configuration from the config file? If --reload is not used the cached version of the pervious valid configuration will be used. In order for the configuration to be picked up by the data nodes also they have to be restarted.

Bernd